# Django extending objects manager raises 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: django, model, django-custom-manager

I am trying to create a custom objects manager as described https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#modifying-initial-manager-querysets

I am doing something like this:

```
# the model, say Alpha
class MyManager(Manager):
    pass
Alpha.objects = MyManager()
```

Which I think should not do anything. But just setting this raises `'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'`. How is this possible? I think I am following the example rather closely.

I checked and `Alpha.objects` before the overwrite is the same type as `svGroup.objects.__class__.__bases__[0]()` afterwards (so it is indeed an instance of a subclass).

I have a feeling this is going to be one of my more stupid questions but I can't figure it out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be inside the model definition. Because it's handling with the __new__ method of model's metaclass.

```
class Alpha(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = MyManager()
```

Comment: @Fatih What if we cannot modify the Alpha class(it's a 3rd party library for example). Is there any workaround in this case?

Comment: @KhaNguyễn Maybe monkey-patching? `Alpha.objects = MyManager()`