# Django: Overriding 'objects' of superclass without changing the code in superclass

Tags: django, oop, django-models

I have 2 classes defined like:

```
class Parent(models.Model)
    # class definition
```

And the second class:

```
class Child(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        pass
```

Now I want to override the 'objects' of class Parent. Normally it will go like this:

```
class Parent():
    objects = Child()
```

But I can't modify class Parent because it's a third party library.
Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: there is two **different** parent classes?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge No, there is only one Parent class. The Parent class below is how it's supposed to be modified. But since the Parent class is a third party library I cannot modify it

Comment: are you trying to **access** `child class object` from `parent class` ?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge No. The situation is like this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032329/django-extending-objects-manager-raises-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-met. I however cannot change the Alpha class just like the answer does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setattr(Parent, 'objects', Child())
```

write this line in end of file where you have your manager class.
this will override the objects attribute of Parent Class if exist or add objects attribute.
Example:

```
from django.db import models

class abc(models.Model):
    pass


class pqr(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('in get_queryset')

setattr(abc, 'objects', pqr())
```

now in shell get or create object of parent class in this example ***abc*** class and perform any operation on in .

```
a = abc()
a.objects.all()
```

> **but this method is wrong it will override the objects attribute and if you want to use this method then use attribute name different than objects**